# MySQL select based on daily timestamp range

Tags: mysql, sql, select, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am trying to select data from a table based on timestamps (stored as int(10)). The timestamps correspond to unix timestamps. I am using MySQL 5.

**Question**: How can I select the data based on the following rule: get all records, where the timestamp is from 9 to 10 o'clock. Nothing else. Timestamp could be in the 70's or today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing the value as a UNIX timestamp, you'll need to convert the value into MySQL's timestamp format before using the HOUR function.

```
WHERE HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) = 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`HOUR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) (assuming column is called `timestamp`)

```
WHERE HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) = 9
```

Comment: But doesn't this give me a range from 9 to 11?