# Select timestamp range in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I am trying to select a specific time range on a specific days range in SQL postgres. PLease see the code below which gives an error on the '10:00:00'.
The type of data for each columns is :
numeric for "balance",
character varying(255) for "currency",
timestamp without time zone for "created_at" (ex: 2018-03-20 00:00:00).

I tried this link without success.
[MySQL select based on daily timestamp range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539268/mysql-select-based-on-daily-timestamp-range)

```
SELECT SUM(bl.balance) AS balance, bl.currency, bl.created_at
  FROM balance_logs bl
  WHERE bl.balance_scope = 'system' AND
        created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - 2 AND
        created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND
        created_at BETWEEN '10:00:00' AND '11:00:00'
  GROUP BY bl.currency, bl.created_at
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a `edit` button just below the tags) and include a description of the columns in your table, with the data type of each. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison needs to be as a time:

```
SELECT SUM(bl.balance) AS balance, bl.currency, bl.created_at
FROM balance_logs bl
WHERE bl.balance_scope = 'system' AND
      created_at >= CURRENT_DATE - 2 AND
      created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND
      created_at::time BETWEEN '10:00:00'::time AND '11:00:00'::time
GROUP BY bl.currency, bl.created_at
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

However, I think it is better to write the `WHERE` condition as:

```
      extract(hour from created_at) = 10
```

Comment: @gordinlinoff thanks. I was wondering if it is possible to modify only a part of a timestamp and you teach me that it is. Thanks